# AngularJS - Accessing my factories in a module?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, factory

I have created a custom module as follows:

```
function(window, angular, undefined, $, _) {
define(['app/scripts/config/resources'], function(config) {
    var ngCLGModule = angular.module('clg-module', []);

    ngCLGModule.factory('factory1', function() {
        return { /* My Factory 1 Methods */ }
    });  

    ngCLGModule.factory('factory2', function() {
        return { /* My Factory 2 Methods */ }
    });

});
});
```

I want to be able to now inject say `factory1` into `factory2`. I tried using

```
ngCLGModule.factory('factory2', ['factory1', function(factory1) {
    return { /* My Factory 2 Methods */ }
}]);
```

But nothing is injected and `factory1` is undefined. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, then I figured my mistake out; it was quite simple actually.

Here is what I WAS doing (which is wrong):

```
ngCLGModule.factory('factory2', ['factory1', function(factory1) {
    return { /* My Factory 2 Methods */ }
}]);
```

Here is what I should do (which is right):

```
ngCLGModule.factory('factory2', function(factory1) {
    return { /* My Factory 2 Methods */ }
});
```

Notice how I don't pass the argument `factory1` as part of an array into the second argument of the resource.

For anyone interested, [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/dependency-injection.html) helped me out.

Comment: Both notations are acceptable in AngularJS Dependency Injection, even the article you mentioned talks about such notation. The former protects you against minification while the latter does not.